# Section heading with quotes and brackets

Tags: sectioning

I am writing the appendix for my thesis in which I am briefly reviewing some reference publications. I would ideally want to name the sections after the publications with the author list captured within brackets, followed by the year of publication. This is recommended for ease of browsing. For instance

```
\section{Review of "Some Publication Title" \[authored by Tom, Dick and Harry\] Published in 2000}
```

I am not able to get past the compilation if I use the above format, as I get the following error:

**! Undefined control sequence.**

Can anyone point me to the correct way of formatting this section heading? I have not provided a MWE in this case, as I believe that this question is quite generic.

TIA

Vinod

P.S:

### MWE follows

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % heading format
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{setpagesize=false, a4paper=true, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue,citecolor=black}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{harvard}            % referencing format. Use with \bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{graphicx}           % including eps or pdf graphics
\usepackage{url}                % format web, email, and file names
\usepackage{caption}            % figure captions
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.15}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\setlength{\floatsep}{2pt plus 2pt minus 5pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{5pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

% some options which should be set up for the caption package
\captionsetup{margin=2ex, font=small, labelsep=colon, aboveskip=2mm, belowskip=2mm}

\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{quotes}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{a4pdf}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Publication Review} \label{chap:appendb}
\section{Source "Publication Title" (authored by Tom, Dick and Harry) Published in 2000}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use `\[` use just `[`.

Comment: `\[` is the opener for the display style math environment, `\]` closes it. This should not appear in a section heading

Comment: @YiannisLazarides No that does not help, I already tried that....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ok, any suggestions on how to format the section the way I want it? Evidently, what I am doing is not right.

Comment: @Vinod: You know the name of the drill: MWE. From that tiny fragment it's guessing only.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: As I had indicated, this is a very generic question IMHO, and I presume that the gist of the question would be the same, irrespective of MWE....but I can edit my question if one is still needed

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere else. MWE please

Comment: Please use proper LaTeX quote marks or use package `csquotes` for your quotation needs.

Comment: `a4pdf`... and a lot of unneeded packages

Comment: `quotes` package is the villain. Remove it and replace it by `csquotes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works without much ado.

Typesetting square brackets can be done with `[` and `]` without any further requirements. `\[` and `\]` are used for the display math environment, which was formerly written `$$...$$` (being deprecated now!)

Does it look nice? **No!**

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} not really needed


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[Some Publication Title]{Review of "Some Publication Title" [authored by Tom, Dick and Harry] Published in 2000}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Since the OP provided an MWE, the error seems to be the `quotes` package. It should be replaced with `csquotes`.

Comment: I will take your solution....

Answer (score 3):

Never use `"` for typing in quotes.

```
\section{Source ``Publication Title'' [authored by Tom, Dick and Harry] Published in 2000}
```

You see that

```
``
```

is used for the opening quotes and

```
''
```

(two apostrophes) is used for the closing quotes.

There's no need to escape `[` and `]`, because they are printable characters so you can and should input them normally.

If you load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and save your file as UTF-8, you can also use the specific characters:

```
\section{Source “Publication Title” [authored by Tom, Dick and Harry] Published in 2000}
```